# Extra misplaced pixel in border

Tags: html, css, animation, border

I made a test header to do my animations in.

[image]

What the thick red line does is to slide to the next header if the user clicks on it. It works fine for Home, About, and Contact...

[image]

[image]

but for some reason, Gallery has an extra misplaced pixel. (You might have to zoom in)

[image: Misplaced pixel]

Here is the HTML :

```
 <div id="header2">
    <div id="sliderArea2">
      <div id="slider2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainHeaders2">
      <div> Home </div>
      <div> About </div>
      <div> Gallery </div>
      <div> Contact </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The click actions :

```
$("#mainHeaders2 div").click(function(){
    var index = $("#mainHeaders2 div").index(this);
    $("#slider2").animate({marginLeft:index*25+"%"});
});
```

And the CSS :

```
#slider1,#slider2{
    height:4px;
    width:23%;
    background-color:red;
}

#sliderArea1, #sliderArea2 {
    height:4px;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    /*border:1px solid; /* debugging purposes */
}

#mainHeaders1, #mainHeaders2 {
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
}

#mainHeaders1 div{
    width:22%;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-right:2%;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-top:1px solid red;
    /*border:1px solid; /*debugging */
    overflow:hidden;

}

#mainHeaders2 div{
    width:22%;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    margin-right:2%;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-top:1px solid red;
    /*border:1px solid; /*debugging */
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

FYI, I replicated this issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqmd9wdz/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use % there is a chance that the width might not get divided properly. Let's say you have 3 items and you assign a width of 33% to each of them. If the browser's width is 100, then there's a chance that 1 of your items might get 34 as the computed width while the other 2 get 33. To be pixel perfect, try setting a fixed width that's a multiple of the number of items you have so the width gets divided evenly among your headers, or just assign a fixed width to each of your individual headers.